# Angular 4/5 HttpClient custom service

Tags: angular, service, dependency-injection, angular4-httpclient

I'm quite new with Angular but i would make a very simple thing (and i'm not able to do)...I want to create a 'base service' which communicates with my api backend but before sets some stuff(headers, variable ... and so)... all others services have to call this 'base service' to communicate with api...here my code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpRequest, HttpHeaders, HttpParams, HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { responseModel } from '../models/response.model';

@Injectable()
export  class  BaseService {

    public headers: HttpHeaders;

    constructor(private _http: HttpClient) {  
        this.headers = new HttpHeaders();
        this.headers.append('Accept', 'application/json, */*');
        this.headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=UTF-8');
    }

    private callBackEnd(relativeEndPoint: string,reqMethod: string,
        reqParams?: HttpParams, objBody?: any): Observable<responseModel> {

        const reqUrl = 'https://mypath/' + relativeEndPoint;
        return this._http.request<responseModel>(reqMethod, reqUrl,
            {
                body: objBody,
                headers: this.headers,
                params: reqParams,
                responseType: 'json',
                withCredentials: true
            }
        );
    }

    handleError(error: any): Observable<responseModel> {
        const out: responseModel= {
            error: !error.ok,
            code: "10",
            message: "no connection",
            more_info: "info@cr",
            response: {}
        }

        return Observable.create(observer => {
            observer.next(out);
            observer.complete();
        });
    }
}
```

it's very simple...every service in which there's a DI of 'BaseService' can call

```
/*IMPORT EVERYTHING*/

@Injectable()
export class CustomService {

  constructor(private _http: BaseService) {

  }

  examplefunction(): Observable<responseModel> 
  {
      return this._http.callBackEnd( '/user/', 'GET')
      .map(
          response => {
               console.log( JSON.stringify(response));
          return response;
          }
          )
   }

}
```

I create a simple Component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CustomService } from './CustomService.service';
import { responseBE } from '../global/models/response.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-simple',
  templateUrl: './simple.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./simple.component.css']
})
export class SimpleComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private _service: CustomService ) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this._service.examplefunction()
      .map(res => {
        console.log(res);
      });
  }

}
```

but nothing works :(

any idea?

Comment: have you got a JS error?

Comment: nothing ... everything seems to be perfect, but no get request seems to be made

Comment: weird, because your callBackEnd in BaseService is private. So, into CustomService you cann't acces to it

Comment: As @mickaelw said, you need to remove the private modifier from your callBackEnd method.

Comment: Also, you need to provide your BaseService somewhere. Probably in your app.module. So you can do something like this:
 import { BaseService } from './base.service';

bootstrap(App, [
   baseService
]);

Comment: You need to subscribe to an observable to make something happen. You are not doing that anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are missing subscribe as the Observable needs subscription to execute.

```
this._service.examplefunction()
  .subscribe(res => {
    console.log(res);
  });
```